# ADODB special char in query

Tags: php, ms-access, adodb

I'm using ADODB and PHP for work with a MS Access DB.
When I call this code:

```
$rs->fields["Unità_amministrativa"]
```

The Server give me back this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Unità_amministrativa in C:\www\SIT-TI\PROGETTI\scheda.php on line 69
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the character encoding of your PHP script file. The following code works for me when the script file is encoded as ANSI...

[image: ansi.png]

...but the exact same code fails when the script file is encoded as UTF-8:

[image: utf8.png]

Comment: Thanks so much,
I solved by inserting "chr(224)" in the string 
"$rs->fields["Unit".chr(224)."_amministrativa"]"